# OperationalError at /admin/todo/todo/ in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a basic Todo app in Django.

While going to the admin page and clicking on the Todo option:

[image: The Todo option i have created]

It gives me this error:

[image: see the address bar]

The "todo" string appears twice in the URL.

I have already done the migrations thing and I have added the `todo.apps.TodoConfig` in the INSTALLED_APPS.

Here is my code:

**todo app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from todo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('todo/', views.index,)
]`
```

**todo app views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello ")
```

**todo app models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**todo app admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Todo

admin.site.register(Todo)
```

**The main project urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ToDoList/', include('ToDoList.urls')),
    path('Todo/', include('todo.urls')),

]
```

Comment: Are you sure you've done both `makemigrations` and `migrate` without errors?

Comment: @Gasanov yes i have done that .
And now it showed :No migration to apply"

Comment: Did you mess with migrations earlier? Try deleting them all (`migrations` directory in `todo`) and dropping your database, then try both commands again.

Comment: is `todo` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?  When you did makemigrations did you do `python manage.py makemigrations todo` the first time to ensure it is picked up?

Comment: Also try using `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb todo`

Comment: @HenryM i used python manage.py makemigrations and then i used python manage.py migrate but not the one that you mentioned

Comment: @dmitryro it shows No migration to apply

Comment: @Gasanov deleting the directory still shows no migrations to apply

Comment: @Mayank dropping database and run `migrate` should at least show migrations that were applied (since your db is empty). Try renaming your application in `apps.py` and do it all over again.

Comment: @Manyank you need to first generate migrations with `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: @Gasanov yeah i am going to startover

Comment: @dmitryro i did that then i used migrate

Comment: show the migrations files

Answer (score 1):

try saving the admin.py file
maybe in admin.py add this code:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Todo

admin.site.register(Todo)
```

Check It And Go!!!

Answer (score 0):

*Even this question is opened on 5 May, 2020, I'll let the response for future noobies that will come to see the problem.*

I've been doing the same tutorial you've done so that's how I solved that issue:

First of all you have to save, then migrate and in the final make migrations even the terminal is showing you that there are no changes made.

First of all:

```
control + s (SAVE)
```

Then:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Finally:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

After you run those commands, you are ready to run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And you can manage tasks from django-admin.

Have a good one!